# shell_exec() unable to execute certain commands

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I was just testing and fiddling around with security stuff when I noticed that I cannot get a result from the following:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('history'); ?>
```

The same refers to:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('fc -l 1'); ?>
```

Both have been tried with `2>&1` at the end but after all - `history` is not a command. Tried under CLI as well:

```
php -r "echo shell_exec('fc -l 1');"
```

which does not return anything. Has been attempted with `system()` and `exec()` also (=does not return a result). In the same time:

- I can execute both `history` and `fc -l 1` via SSH;
- I can execute other commands such as `ls` via PHP (`shell_exec()` both on web and in CLI);
- I am running the same user;
- `history` and `fc -l 1` do return results;

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the same user? try `whoami` both ways to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it is the same user. Did confirm this with `whoami`.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know, sorry

Comment: `shell_exec` runs Bourne Shell. `history` and `fc` are extensions in `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec()` runs `sh`. History is an extension feature available in other shells such as `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, but not generally in `sh` (on some operating systems, `sh` is a link to `bash`, but `bash` checks the name it was run with and disables many extensions when called as `sh`).

You could do:

```
shell_exec("bash -c 'history'");
```

to run `bash` and execute its `history` command.

Note also that the history mechanism is normally only enabled in interactive shells, not shells invoked from programs.

Comment: I just tried it. Returns `NULL`. Could you verify it's working on your end?

Comment: Like I wrote, non-interactive shells don't keep history. So why would you expect it to return anything?

Comment: This just prevents it from getting an error saying that the command is not found.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Should read up more on the topic. Thank you for your time and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It seems that most shells have long included the `history` command as a **shell built-in**. From Wikipedia:

> A shell builtin is a command or a function, called from a shell, that
>   is executed directly in the shell itself, instead of an external
>   executable program which the shell would load and execute.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin

PHP shell callouts are handled by `sh`, but most sane people use `bash` which stores its history elsewhere. As well, shell history is generally only written by interactive shells during a graceful close.